# bluetoothctl: list connected devices?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, kubuntu

I'm trying to get a list of connected Bluetooth devices via the command line on Kubuntu.

When I launch [`bluetoothctl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/bluetoothctl.1.html), it defaults to the latest connected device, and I need to disconnect it to display the other one.

Is there a way to list the connected Bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 18):

Here's a **fish-shell** one-liner (see below for **bash**)

```
bluetoothctl devices | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read uuid; bluetoothctl info $uuid; end|grep -e "Device\|Connected\|Name"
```

**bash** one-liner:

```
bluetoothctl devices | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read uuid; do bluetoothctl info $uuid; done|grep -e "Device\|Connected\|Name"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can list paired devices with `bluetoothctl paired-devices`

From this list you can get info for each device with `bluetoothctl info`
On the info you have the Connected status.

So loop on each devices grep for `Connected: yes` if so display the name:

```
bluetoothctl paired-devices | cut -f2 -d' '|
while read -r uuid
do
    info=`bluetoothctl info $uuid`
    if echo "$info" | grep -q "Connected: yes"; then
       echo "$info" | grep "Name"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

As of bluez/bluetoothctl 5.65 (`bluetoothctl --version`), we can use `bluetoothctl devices Connected` (Capitalized **C**) to list connected bluetooth devices. For example:

```
$ bluetoothctl devices Connected
Device AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF MY-DEVICE-NAME
```

If you care about paired devices, use `bluetoothctl devices Paired` for bluez/bluetoothctl version >= 5.65, or `bluetoothctl paired-devices` for bluez/bluetoothctl < 5.65.

Answer (score 2):

This may help: `sudo bluetoothctl info MAC-ADDRESS-OF-DEVICE`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Would you mind explaining how that would help the person who asked the question?

Comment: I get `Missing device address arguments`

Comment: @Swedgin this means you have no connected devices.

Comment: I see my headphones listed when i run `bluetoothctl paired-devices` -- but when I run `bluetoothctl info` I still get the error `Missing device address argument`...

Comment: @CarlWalsh, the error tells you exactly what you're missing: `bluetoothctl info` gives information about _a single_ device, thus you need to tell it the MAC address of the device you want to get information about.

Answer (score 1):

After running `sudo bluetoothctl`...

you can type `paired-devices` to see a list of paired devices
or `list` to see a list of currently connected controllers

you can also type `info` to see info about each device.

Each command here supports tab completion of MAC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to display the currently connected device in my Swaybar:

```bsh
bluetoothctl devices | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read uuid; do bluetoothctl info $uuid; done | grep -e "Name\|Connected: yes" | grep -B1 "yes" | head -n 1 | cut -d\  -f2-
```

Breakdown:

```bsh
bluetoothctl devices
# List all devices

cut -f2 -d' '
# Cut out the second column containing the MAC address

while read uuid; do bluetoothctl info $uuid; done 
# For each MAC address call bluetoothctl info

grep -e "Name\|Connected: yes"
# Find all lines that have either name or Connected: yes

grep -B1 "yes"
# Find the line with yes and the line before that line

head -n 1
# Return the last line

cut -d\  -f2-
# Return the second column and all other columns for the device name
```